# Duplicity works with run-parts but not in anacron

Tags: bash, backup, cron, anacron

I am working to set up backups from my computer to Google Cloud Storage using duplicity.

I used `gsutil` to create a `~/.boto` configuration file, and created a simple bash script that includes a call to duplicity everything works just fine when I run `$ sudo run-parts /etc/cron.daily`.

However, when it runs in anacron I get a long Traceback which ends with the following exception:

```
NoAuthHandlerFound: No handler was ready to authenticate. 1 handlers were 
checked. ['HmacAuthV1Handler'] Check your credentials
```

It seems like the most likely culprit is that there's something in my environment which is not also present in the cron environment.

I tried copying my `PATH` to `/etc/anacrontab` and changing `SHELL` to `/bin/bash` but that doesn't appear to have worked.

Comment: I wonder if the difference is that with `sudo` (**without** the `-H`), your `$HOME` still points to where you created `~/.boto`, whereas with `anacron` `$HOME` is either `/root` or possibly empty?

Comment: If you post the contents of the "simple bash script" people can look at it and probably identify the problem.

Comment: @steeldriver - thanks so much! I change `$HOME` in the script and it worked perfectly.